# How to extract two types of sequences using fasta headers with awk statements

Tags: awk

I have been running a program called genewise to translate nucleotide sequences into protein sequences for a gene. The input includes assembled nucleotide sequences from many samples. To parse the genewise output, I have been selecting on the fasta header with the following command:

```
for i in `ls`; do (cd "$i" && awk '/^>*/{flag=1;} /\/\// {flag=0}flag' out_genewise > out_genewise_prot.fa);done
```

I was asked to rerun genewise for each gene so that the output includes both the translated protein sequences and the cDNA sequences for all samples. I am having trouble creating two awk statements to parse the output.

For each sample in the genewise output for a gene, the protein fasta header has .sp.tr at the end and the nucleotide has .sp at the end which can distinguish between the two types of sequences.

Here is an example of one of the sequences.

```
 >303.1_assembled_PF3D7_1477500.[1:1643].sp.tr
 MNLRLSNYSLFQNILDKTNKSNCIYSTHSSYEEYHDEKVRTGSFFYSKKFRRYMLPIMGI
 LYIIILNLLHLKGILSTEVQRSYTFSRNLSDNEKEKEKEKENKEFYKCYKKKGIKKLTIE
 EEDLYPRHPGLYNSYYDYERPYLLTPEMLEYIEKAVEENVEKEVERRAIESFENRMLKQF
 VDEIRDKRLRKGTI
 //
 >303.1_assembled_PF3D7_1477500.[1:1643].sp
 ATGAATTTAAGGCTATCAAACTATAGTTTGTTTCAAAATATTCTTGATAAAACGAATAAA
 TCGAATTGTATTTATTCTACACACAGTTCTTACGAAGAATATCATGATGAAAAAGTAAGA
 GAAAAAGAAGTTGAAAGGAGAGCTATAGAATCATTTGAAAATAGAATGCTAAAACAGTTT
 GTAGATGAAATAAGAGATAAAAGATTAAGAAAAGGTACCATT
 //
```

I tried the command below to parse the data but no files are being created. Can someone help me with fixing my commands?

```
 for i in `ls`; do (cd "$i" && awk '/^>*.sp.tr/{flag=1;} /\/\// {flag=0}flag' out_genewise > out_genewise_prot.fa);done

 for i in `ls`; do (cd "$i" && awk '/^>*.sp$/{flag=1;} /\/\// {flag=0}flag' out_genewise > out_genewise_nt.fa);done
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: where are the `//` in the data file to mark the end of extract?

Comment: Each nucleotide sequence or protein sequence ends with a //. I have updated my original post to show it properly.

Comment: @tkh86, please add expected output more clearly, as it is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

your regex is not correctly set, this should work in one pass to create both files

```
$ awk '/^>.*sp\.tr$/ {suf="prot"} 
       /^>.*sp$/     {suf="nt"} 
       /\/\//        {suf=""} 
       suf           {print > FILENAME"_"suf".na"}' file
```

`.` means any char `*` means 0 or more times. `/^>*.sp/` will match ">xsp" or "xsp" but not ">xxsp" where x is any char (other than >)

Comment: Yes, I see what you are are saying. Thank you so much for the code and explanation. I will give it a try.